# Dialogflow CX - need to implement an "I need more time" functionality where the Agent waits for a longer period of time

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Here is the context: we have a flow where we gather information from the user, and sometimes the user needs additional time to find a document or something like that.

For example, the Agent asks "What is your driver's license number?", the user doesn't have the document handy, then they can say "I need more time" or "I'll be right back". When this intent is matched, we would like to wait longer (say - one minute instead of the default 5 seconds of a regular sys.no-input) to give the user an opportunity to gather the information.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to do this by leveraging the sys.no-input-default and sys.no-match-default and introducing a counter of how many times no-input was triggered. no-match helps ignore when the user says something unrelated, or some background noise interferes with the conversation.